# Understanding TAOCP paragraph "Will Keysorting help" in "external" sorting?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Near the end of subsection *5.4.9 Disks and Drums* in *5.4. External Sorting*, a process is sketched in a paragraph headed *Will Keysorting help?*:

> Schematically, the process has the following form:

> | stage | input | data sequence | length |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | i) | Original file | $(K_1,I_1)(K_2,I_2)\dots(K_N,I_N)$ | long |
> | ii) | Key file | $(K_1,1)(K_2,2)\dots(K_N,N)$ | short |
> | iii) | Sorted (ii) | $(K_{p_1},p_1)(K_{p_2},p_2)\dots(K_{p_N},p_N)$ | short |
> | iv) | Edited (iii) | $(1,p_1)(2,p_2)\dots(N,p_N)$ | short |
> | v) | Sorted (iv) | $(q_1,1)(q_2,2)\dots(q_N,N)$ | short |
> | vi) | (i) | $(q_1,I_1)(q_2,I_2)\dots(q_N,I_N)$ | long |

> here, $p_j = k$ if and only if $q_k = j$…

I am not able to understand the need for step (iv) in that process.
Why edit (iii) and replace it with `1,2,..N`
- when (iii) can be written to disk as a run?

Comment: Please add to your question what that process is about. For other editions, give the "Dewey-decimal" designation. Better yet, present the steps (fair use).

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you make the question self-contained, by explaining whatever context is needed to understand what you're asking, including what the steps refer to, so we don't have to have a copy of Knuth's book open in front of us to understand the question.

Comment: (Seems to be in *5.4.9 (Sorting using) Disks and Drums*, about two pages before the exercises. In the 1973 edition, the lines are designated by Latin letters rather than Roman numbers. None shows `1,2,..N`.)

Comment: Thanks for editing the question @greybeard

Comment: [TAOCP vol 3 Page page 384](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/The%20Art%20of%20Computer%20Programming%20%28vol.%203_%20Sorting%20and%20Searching%29%20%282nd%20ed.%29%20%5BKnuth%201998-05-04%5D.pdf#page=384) @D.W. for anyone not having access to TAOCP.